# PHP mail subject with german letters

Tags: php, email

I have here maybe a simple problem, but I don't understand why it doesnt' work, I have research and tried many examples, I am posting you my current example, I have this from a tutorial where they have explain this is the solution, but in my case it doesn't work, the subject in the email which I get does not show the letters "Ä Ö Ü ß ü" correctly.

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: {$emailfrom}";

$to = "myemail@yahoo.de";
$subject = 'Betreff mit Ä, Ö und Ü ß ü';
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';


$txt = "Hallo Sie haben das gewählt, am &#xE4; ";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,implode("\r\n",$headers));
```

Normally they write everywhere in the different tutorials this is the solution but in my case it doesn't work, why? Maybe have it something to do with the moon in my case? lol ;)

Comment: Instead of base64_encode, try quoted_printable_encode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [mb_encode_mimeheader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php),

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
$subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject,'UTF-8','Q');
```

It will take care of encoding to Quoted-printable when needed(the human readable). Hope it should be solve your problem.

Comment: You are great, it have slove the problem. Respect for the knowledge of some people.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to pick one encoding, save the HTML file using that encoding, and make sure that you declare that encoding in at least one of the ways. As for what encoding to use, Germans usually use ISO/IEC 8859-15, but UTF-8 is a good alternative that can handle any kind of non-ASCII characters at the same time.

First ways is that is using utf 8

```
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Second Way is using charset according to german language

```
    $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO/IEC 8859-15\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to base64 encode your subject... Just the following works fine:

```
<?php

$emailfrom = 'Some Name <somename@someserver.com>';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: $emailfrom";

$to = "myemail@yahoo.de";
$subject = 'Betreff mit Ä, Ö und Ü ß ü';
$txt = "Hallo Sie haben das gewählt, am &#xE4; ";

mail($to, $subject, $txt, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

**EDIT:**
Some of the headers that Gmail displays upon executing the above code snippet with a Gmail address:

```
Subject: Betreff mit Ä, Ö und Ü ß ü
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:test.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Hallo Sie haben das gewählt, am &#xE4;
```

Comment: If it would be so easy, no sorry your example looks same, here is a picture: https://s22.postimg.org/rwxdtjje9/mail.png    it looks always like this - > Betreff mit �, � und � � �

Comment: i dont understand what you mean in your edit info, but doesent work, i dont understand, maybe its because i use a free webhosting provider?

Comment: It rather looks like your email client is not respecting the charset you specify in the headers. If you are using my example, you send an email with neatly UTF-8 encoded strings. Check whether your subject looks bad in multiple mail clients...

Comment: no look above somebody have give me a solution, it works with this code: $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject,'UTF-8','Q');   sometimes like you see its not so easy to find the reason

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: {$emailfrom}";

$to = "myemail@yahoo.de";
$subject = 'Betreff mit Ä, Ö und Ü ß ü';
$subject = str_replace("");
$subjects = '=?UTF-8?B?'.$subject.'?=';


$txt = "Hallo Sie haben das gewählt, am &#xE4; ";
mail($to,$subjects,$txt,implode("\r\n",$headers));
```

If you have the same wrong output means please refer the iconv() in php it gives solution for your problem.. all the best buddy..

Comment: Thanks, but your example looks also wrong, it does not show me the correct letters:  a picture: https://s22.postimg.org/rwxdtjje9/mail.png    it looks always like this - > Betreff mit �, � und � � �    Maybe this problem comes from anywhere else